# Android application to communicate with c# exe using TCP Connection

Tags: c#, android, sockets

I am trying to make an application which communicates with C# exe running on the server.
When i am running the application, it is giving me an error : **Emulator without GPU emulation detected** What should i do?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked if any of the [13 other questions that mention this error](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Emulator+without+GPU+emulation+detected%22) solves your problem?

Comment: Yeah, i have tried those but not much of help. Just deduced that if i add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> in android manifest, i get this error. Otherwise it shows Permission denied.